# Image registration issue using OpenCV&Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, alignment, registration

I’m trying to register 2 images with some minor alignments and then check the difference between of them with the above code, But I’m getting strange aligned image although the detected keypoints match in these 2 images seems to be very good.

The images is:

Image 1:
[image: Image 1]

Image 2:
[image: Image 2]

The tif format makes the images too big to upload so I upload a screenshot of the images.

- The white circle in the center is some elemet that I need to hide for some reasons, But still we can made the images registrations also only from the '15' pattern in the upper right area.

I also normalize image 2 to image 1 brightness with this code as a pre-process:

```
# Convert images to grayscale
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(self.img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(self.img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# crop the images to ROI - The ROI is the same for both images and is the left bottom corner in size of 1/5 of the image
img1_roi = img1[0:int(img1.shape[0] / 5), 0:int(img1.shape[1] / 5)]
img2_roi = img2[0:int(img2.shape[0] / 5), 0:int(img2.shape[1] / 5)]

# Calculate the mean of the images.
mean_img1 = np.mean(img1_roi)
mean_img2 = np.mean(img2_roi)

# Calculate the ratio of the brightness of the images.
ratio = mean_img1 / mean_img2
print(f'Brightness ratio: {ratio}')

# Multiply the second image by the ratio.
self.img2 = self.img2 * ratio

# Convert the image to uint8 again.
self.img2 = np.clip(self.img2, 0, 255)
self.img2 = self.img2.astype(np.uint8)
```

And here is my main code:

```
image1 = cv2.cvtColor(self.img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(self.img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
height, width = image2.shape

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

keypoints1, descriptors1 = sift.detectAndCompute(image1, None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image2, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

matches = bf.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, k=2)

good_matches = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)
src_pts = np.float32([keypoints1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
dst_pts = np.float32([keypoints2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

draw_params = dict(singlePointColor=None, flags=2)
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(image1, keypoints1, image2, keypoints2, good_matches, None, **draw_params)
```

Matches output:

[image: Matches output]

```
aligned_image = cv2.warpAffine(image2, M[0:2, :], (image1.shape[1], image1.shape[0]))
```

Aligned image:

[image: Aligned image]

```
difference = cv2.absdiff(image1, aligned_image)
threshold = 10  # Adjust this threshold as per your requirements
change_mask = cv2.threshold(difference, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

Difference image:

[image: Difference image]

I also tried Fourie method on the ROI of '15' pattern:

```
def _correlate_images(self, image1, image2):
    # compute the correlation coefficient between two images
    correlation = signal.correlate2d(image1, image2, boundary='symm', mode='same')
    return correlation

def _compute_shift_distance(self, image1, image2):
    # compute the shift distance between two images
    correlation = self._correlate_images(image1, image2)
    (y, x) = np.unravel_index(correlation.argmax(), correlation.shape)
    (tH, tW) = image2.shape[:2]
    shift_distance = (x - tW // 2, y - tH // 2)
    return shift_distance

def _align_images_fourier_mellin(self, image1, image2):
    # align images using Fourier-Mellin transform

    # compute the Fourier Transform of both images, then compute the
    # magnitude spectrum
    fft1 = np.fft.fft2(image1)
    fft2 = np.fft.fft2(image2)
    magnitude_spectrum1 = 20 * np.log(np.abs(fft1))
    magnitude_spectrum2 = 20 * np.log(np.abs(fft2))

    # find the peak in the correlation map
    correlation = self._correlate_images(magnitude_spectrum1, magnitude_spectrum2)
    (x, y) = np.unravel_index(correlation.argmax(), correlation.shape)

    # compute the shift distance
    (delta_x, delta_y) = self._compute_shift_distance(image1, image2)

    # use the shift distance to translate the image
    M = np.float32([[1, 0, delta_x], [0, 1, delta_y]])
    shifted = cv2.warpAffine(image2, M, (image2.shape[1], image2.shape[0]))

    # return the aligned image
    return shifted


image1_roi = image1[int(height / 5.5):int(height / 2.5), int(2.5 * width / 4):width]
image2_roi = image2[int(height / 5.5):int(height / 2.5), int(2.5 * width / 4):width]
aligned_image = self._align_images_fourier_mellin(image1_roi, image2_roi)
```

And after few minutes of running I get this results:

[image: aligned image by Fourie]

[image: aligned full image by Fourie]

[image: Fourie diffs]

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Post your two input images without the match points drawn between them. How do you expect us the test your code without the images?

Comment: that thumbnail of the matches (whyyyyyy? provide it in 1:1 resolution, NEVER just thumbnails) tells me that you don't have any matches in the bottom left corner. that's very odd. do you at least have features there?

Comment: You could try a more robust alignment method. For example Fourier-Mellin.

Comment: NB: I've given FM a look... it determines scale and rotation, i.e. translation has to have been estimated already. do I get that right? haven't found a good description of the algorithm yet, just wikipedia-level material.

Comment: There may be a small offset of rotation between the images but it is really not big - you can see it in the element of the 15th.
I also tried with Fourier's algorithm but I got unreasonable running times - a few minutes of running..
Thanks!

Comment: because you ran the fourier on the full scale inputs, which are what, 10000 by 10000? consider what precision you really need.

Comment: Also in small ROI it's takes very long time

Comment: show what you did. can't debug prose.

Comment: I've added the code and results with Fourier-Mellin method on ROI

Comment: that looks like plain convolution (which would be done using fft, elementwise multiplication, ifft). convolution can estimate spatial shift but nothing more. to estimate any other two dimensions, that would require transformations. and it still can't estimate more than two dimensions overall. -- what `shift_distance` does that code return? I'm asking for exact values. I think they'll be 0 or close to it. if you correlate spectra, you're correlating frequencies, and those are most likely to have no shift to each other.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz No, Fourier-Mellin estimates rotation, scaling and translation. It first does the first two on the magnitude of the Fourier transform, which is translation-invariant. Then it uses correlation to find the translation after applying the first two transformations. It’s a really neat method. See for example [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57899953/7328782).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I've added an answer showing the Fourier-Mellin result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a good method for alignment of this type is the Fourier-Mellin transform (see for example [this tutorial](https://sthoduka.github.io/imreg_fmt/)). Note that the code added by OP in response to my comment is not the Fourier-Mellin algorithm, it attempts to compute a translation through correlation of the magnitude of the FFT of the two images, which makes no sense).

The DIPlib library [has an implementation of the Fourier-Mellin algorithm](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/analysis.html#dip-FourierMellinMatch2D-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL) (disclaimer: I'm an author of DIPlib, and I wrote this implementation):

```py
import diplib as dip
import numpy as np

# Load the two images
img1 = dip.ImageRead("img1.jpg")
img2 = dip.ImageRead("img2.jpg")

# They're gray-scale images, even if the JPEG file has RGB values
img1 = img1(1)  # just keep the green channel
img2 = img2(1)

# They need to be the same size
out_size = np.minimum(img1.Sizes(), img2.Sizes())
img1.Crop(out_size)
img2.Crop(out_size)

# Note that these JPEGs are not very big. If the original images are huge, you can
# down-sample them first to improve the efficiency of the operations.

# Apply Fourier-Mellin to transform one image to match the other
out = dip.Image()
matrix = dip.FourierMellinMatch2D(img1, img2, out=out, correlationMethod="don't normalize")

dip.JoinChannels((img1, out)).Show()
```

The `matrix` returned is a list of values useful in other functions of this library, but it is equivalent to this transformation matrix:

```
/ 0.9999 -0.0085 -12.576 \
| 0.0085  0.9999   5.336 |
\ 0.0     0.0      1.0   /
```

That is, it finds only a tiny rotation and 1:1 scaling; the translation is the only relevant element.

The aligned image overlaid on the input images looks like this:

[image: display of original img1 in red and out in green]

It's not a perfect alignment, the numbers match up perfectly, but the ring doesn't on the far side of the numbers. This indicates that a more complex transform is required to match up the two images. Likely the camera angle changed, or the object itself deformed.

Comment: `@Cris Luengo` Is there an OpenCV implementation of Fourier Mellon?

Comment: @fmw42 I don't know, I couldn't find it in OpenCV itself. I did find this code that *uses* OpenCV: https://github.com/Smorodov/LogPolarFFTTemplateMatcher -- I have no idea about its quality though.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that method and have experimented with it myself, though not that particular library. I could not find anything in the OpenCV library per se, but may have missed it. Thought you might know. Thanks.

Comment: For small mis-alignments, I have used cv2.findTransformECC(). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654471/featured-based-image-alignment-issue/59655966#59655966. If distortions are involved, then I do not know if this approach will work.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks, I wasn’t aware of that function. I’ve had some bad experiences with iterative alignment methods, which is why I like Fourier-Mellin so much. But it’s not perfect either.

Comment: There is indeed a slight difference between the size of the object in the 2 images, but overall it looks like an excellent result! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, where I know that the deviation in the angle tends to zero and the main deviation is in the X and Y axes - the following simple relative solution worked best for me:

```
avg_offset_x = 0
avg_offset_y = 0
for i in range(len(good_matches)):
    avg_offset_x += (keypoints2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt[0] - keypoints1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt[0])
    avg_offset_y += (keypoints2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt[1] - keypoints1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt[1])
avg_offset_x /= len(good_matches)
avg_offset_y /= len(good_matches)
# print(f'Average offset: {avg_offset_x}, {avg_offset_y}')

aligned_image = self.img2.copy()
avg_offset_x = -int(avg_offset_x)
avg_offset_y = -int(avg_offset_y)
# add offsets to aligned image to align it with the first image (image1)
aligned_image = np.roll(aligned_image, avg_offset_x, axis=1)
aligned_image = np.roll(aligned_image, avg_offset_y, axis=0)

# Show the aligned image
# cv2.namedWindow('aligned_image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# cv2.imshow("aligned_image", aligned_image)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

self.img2 = aligned_image
```

Hope this helps someone.